# How do I fix "People search relevance is not optimized when the Active Directory has errors in the manager reporting structure"?

Tags: health-analyzer

SharePoint Health Analyzer has detected the following error:

---

People search relevance is not optimized when the Active Directory has errors in the manager reporting structure.

Title : People search relevance is not optimized when the Active Directory has errors in the manager reporting structure.

Severity : 2 - Warning

Category: Configuration

Explanation : In Active Directory, only company leaders should have the 'manager' property set to NULL. As a result of errors, the Active Directory can incorrectly have the 'manager' property set to NULL for other users that can cause a decrease in people search relevance. By specifying the actual leaders of the company, these inconsistencies are not taken into account and the relevance problem is corrected.

Remedy : Specify the company leaders explicitly. Use the following PowerShell commands: $upap = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy [appid]; Add-SPProfileLeader $upap [Domain][UserName]. Run 'Get-SPProfileLeader $upap' to check whether the leader was successfully added. As a last step, run a full crawl on the content source containing the start address (URL) of the user profile application. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2401800".

Failing Servers :

Failing Services : UserProfileService

**Event Viewer Error :**

Source : MSSQL$SHAREPOINT

An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State: 11. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user , error code 0x534.

---

How do I remove this error?

Comment: Just dumping an analyzer message isn't productive.

Comment: If you would like people to answer a question for you, please put in some effort rather than copying and pasting an error message. See our [FAQ#howtoask] for more general guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is quite clear: you have several persons in AD that does not have defined the Manager property. SharePoint uses this to determine managers, colleagues, social distance etc. So it is a good idea to have this property set.

You can always disable a rule in the health monitor if you dont want warnings or errors in event log

Answer (score 3):

Or you should not worry about the ID whatsoever and do the following:

```
$upap = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.typename -eq "User Profile Service Application Proxy"}

Add-SPProfileLeader -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $upap -Name "Domain\Username"
```

This however assumes that you have a single user Profile Service application proxy.

This also assumes that the user domain\username already has a profile in the user profile service.

This user also should not have a manager populated.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.  I no longer receive the warnings in SCA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PowerShell script to manually specify the leader, using the following code from [this blog](http://harbar.net/archive/2011/07/06/329.aspx):

```
$upaProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy 7643a5c2-a6ae-49eb-8ba0-de2f32a890ba
Add-SPProfileLeader -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $upaProxy -Name "contoso\davism"
```

Of course, you would need to substitute the correct application proxy ID and username. You can get a list of your application proxy IDs by running the Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy command in PowerShell.